# BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context) return null

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I upgraded my flutter app version from 3.7.5 to 3.8, integrating the null safety. Since then when I `flutter run` I get this error : `Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value` which correspond to **BlocProvider.of(context)**.

```
//main.dart

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return BlocProvider<MyBloc>(
      blocBuilder: () => MyBloc(),
      blocDispose: (MyBloc bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {'/': (context) => MyBlocCondition()},
      ),
    );
  }
}

//MyBlocCondition

class MyBlocCondition extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MyBloc _myBloc = BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context)!;
    print(context);
    print(_MyBloc);

    return BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
      blocBuilder: () => AuthenticationBloc(),
      blocDispose: (AuthenticationBloc bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
      child: StreamBuilder<bool?>(
        stream: _myBloc.state,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool?> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {

            return LoadingPage();
          }

          if (snapshot.data!) {
            return RootCondition();
          } else {
            return MyBlocPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The 3.7.5 version works fine and the _MyBloc never returns null, so I don't get why the upgrade would cause that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you need to create bloc  like

```dart
 BlocProvider(
   create: (context) => MyBloc(),
   child: MaterialApp(... ///
```

Comment: Changing to the code you suggested gave me the following error:
**The named parameter 'blocBuilder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.**

The structure of the BlocProvider is the following one :
```(new) BlocProvider<BlocBase?> BlocProvider({
  Key? key,
  required Widget child,
  required BlocBase? Function() blocBuilder,
  dynamic Function(BlocBase?)? blocDispose,
})
```

Comment: to read with `BlocProvider` it will be like `BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyState>( builder: (context, state) {`